# Updating an NSMutableArray passed into a method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm very new to objective-c so be easy :-)  I have a container object, "Data", who has a number of NSMutableArrays.

Data.h

```
@interface Data : NSObject{

    NSMutableArray *one;
    NSMutableArray *two;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *one;

@end
```

and would like to pass it to a load method in which case it will update each corresponding array in the Data class.

Parser.h

```
+ (Parser *)load:(Data*) store;
```

Parser.m

```
+ (Parser *)load:(Data *) store {
...

[store.one addObject:name.stringValue];
}
```

But no matter what I do the string in "name.stringValue" doesn't get appended to the array.  Is there something I'm missing when passing in the "Store" data object to the parse method?  Let me know if I should provide more details but I feel this covers the issue.

Comment: Are you sure your array is properly initialized? Just having a property doesn't initialize it, it may just be `nil` and sending a message to `nil` doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: r u allocating the memory of array

Comment: + (NSMutableArray *)load:(Data *) store {
NSMutableArray * store = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSString *str in store)
{
[store addObject:name.stringValue];
}
return store;
} try like this

Comment: Spynet - I get an error since that is redefining what "store" is.  It's being passed in as a "Data" type whereas your setting it to NSMutableArray.

Comment: I tried initializing it in the parse method by doing: store.one = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  but no luck

Comment: do you want to ping me pls add @ symbol then only i got your reply notification example @spynet

Answer (score 1):

Check in your implementation of `Data` that you are properly initializing the mutable arrays - here is a simple example below given your `Data` interface:

```
#import "Data.h"

@implementation Data
{

#pragma mark - Properties

- (NSMutableArray *)one
{
  if (!_one) {
    _one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return _one;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)two
{
  if (!_two) {
    _two = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return _two;
}

}
```

Comment: Excuse the newbie comment but why is there a "one" and a "_one"?  Is the underscored _one being magically generated somewhere?

Comment: Yeh, it's the default instance accessor... to access the variable directly, use `_one`, to access it through the getter within the class use, `self.one`, to access it outside of the class use, `instanceObjectName.one`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm just getting back into compiled code after quite some time so the gears are slowly turning :-)  This approach, while it works, seems really verbose for no more than initializing an array.  Is there a more concise way to perform this action short of one main 'init' function?

Comment: One more question while were on the subject of constructors/initialization.  How would i go about creating an NSArray of class properies so i could loop through and allocate memory?  Haven't gotten very far with using NSArray initWithObjects.  Thanks!

Comment: To your earlier comment, you can also override your constructor and initialize your arrays...  if you search for, "Objective-c override constructor" you will find more information.

Comment: Using properties approach for initializing your array waits until the array is required before creating it, something known as, "lazy loading". I think it's a bit verbose and you can do it simpler by overriding the constructor, but really depends on your trade offs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `one = [NSMutableArray array];` before you start using it. This will create an empty mutable array.